# Looping though form for disabled controls

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a form with input, select,radiobuttons etc where i want to check control ids with attribute [disabled=disabled]

I am trying to apply class to all items at a time and planning to get output with all disabled controls separated by comma. Is my approach correct?

```
<form id="saveForm">
<input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' disabled='disabled'>
<input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' disabled='disabled'>
    etc.,
    </form>

$("input[disabled]").each(function(){
    var testdata = $(this).data('disabled');

});
```

What I am trying to get as output:

'#firstname, #lastname, ....'

Comment: "*planning to get output with all disabled controls separated by comma.*" - what does that mean, exactly? Before we can answer whether your 'approach [is] correct' you first have to clearly explain what result/output you want.

Comment: Thanks for waking me up. What I am trying to get as output:

'#firstname, #lastname, ....'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve a comma-separated list of the `id`s of the disabled elements:

```js
var idsOfDisabled = $('form [disabled]').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get().join(',');
console.log(idsOfDisabled); // firstname,lastname,title
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="saveForm">
  <input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' disabled='disabled' />
  <input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' disabled='disabled' />
  <select disabled="disabled" id="title">
    <option>Mr</option>
    <option>Mrs</option>
    <option>Ms</option>
    <option>Dr.</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

If the `#` character is required, then:

```js
var idsOfDisabled = $('form [disabled]').map(function() {
  return '#' + this.id;
}).get().join(',');
console.log(idsOfDisabled); // #firstname,#lastname,#title
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="saveForm">
  <input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' disabled='disabled' />
  <input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' disabled='disabled' />
  <select disabled="disabled" id="title">
    <option>Mr</option>
    <option>Mrs</option>
    <option>Ms</option>
    <option>Dr.</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Or, further, in plain JavaScript using only the native DOM:

```js
var idsOfDisabled = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('form [disabled]'), function (disabledElem) {
  return '#' + disabledElem.id;
  }).join(',');

console.log(idsOfDisabled);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="saveForm">
  <input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' disabled='disabled' />
  <input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' disabled='disabled' />
  <select disabled="disabled" id="title">
    <option>Mr</option>
    <option>Mrs</option>
    <option>Ms</option>
    <option>Dr.</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: how can we take controls specific to that form with form id?

Comment: Instead of using `$('form [disabled]')` use `$('#saveForm [disabled]')` (similarly, instead of `document.querySelectorAll('form [disabled]')` use `document.querySelectorAll('#saveForm [disabled]')`); it's just a CSS selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:disabled` pseudo selector](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/).

```
$("input:disabled").each(function(){
    var testdata = $(this).data('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be better of using pseudo, `:input` will find all the input element, textarea, checkboxes etc.

```
$(":input:disabled").each(function(){
    var testdata = $(this).data('disabled');
});
```